# BeagleBone Black Software OpenGL

Tags: opengl, debian, beagleboneblack

I am working on an embedded project. The hardware is based on the BeagleBone Black platform.

There seems to be a conflict between the OpenGL hardware driver for the TI GPU and the CAN driver that is causing problems.

We are using Qt5.8 for all our graphics. We are not doing anything fancy, but we are using Qt Quick 2 which requires OpenGL.

Since we are not doing anything fancy software rendering might be fine.

Can someone tell me if there is a way to install some kind of Software implementation of OpenGL on Debian 8 on this platform?

I have heard of Mesa, but can't find details on install it in software rendering mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On Linux, 99% sure you need Mesa, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308154/3871028). Note: nowadays Mesa supports newest OpenGL versions.

If the hardware acceleration has problems for you, try forcing software emulation.

Some hints in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/106056/force-software-based-opengl-rendering)

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks.